# Get WCF metadata through endpoint address

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, wcf-endpoint

I have a wcf service exposing multiple endpoints including a mex endpoint. I have enabled getting the metadata over http and https.

My endpoints are like this...

```
<endpoint name="ep1" address="ep1"....
<endpoint name="ep2" address="ep2"....
<endpoint name="mex" address="mex"....
```

The service behaviour is set properly and I'm able to get the wsdl like this:

```
http://10.10.10.150/MyTestService.svc
```

Is it possible for me to get the wsdl like below:???

```
http://10.10.10.150/ep1/MyTestService.svc
http://10.10.10.150/ep2/MyTestService.svc
http://10.10.10.150/MyTestService.svc/ep1
http://10.10.10.150/MyTestService.svc/ep2
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? Why do you want this?

Comment: I'm able to communicate over the endpoints. That's not a problem. I want to know if the WSDL will be available over the /address path or not.

Comment: As I said before; **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: Academic interest. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a strange question.

If you're exposing multiple endpoints for a service then you're basically exposing the same contract across multiple bindings or on more than one physical address.

If it's the same contract then logically you would never have to expose more than one mex endpoint because the whole point of mex is to describe your service contract, allowing consumers to discover the operations and data contracts defined in your service.

So even if you *were* able to expose multiple mex endpoints they would all describe basically the same thing.

If your question is ***Can I configure the mex endpoint address?*** then the answer is [yes you can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @KSK you're welcome I hope it helps you with your academic understanding ;)